# ExtJS 4.2 larger tab close icon?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

Using ExtJS 4.2, tab close icon is a small x.

How to display a bigger tab close icon ?
(or another way to help users to close tabs)

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres's the [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jmc)
You can change the values, but make sure to keep proportions valid.